# Should all the static methods be synchronised?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, static-methods, synchronous

I will explain the two use-cases here:

1. Static method which uses an object and perform some operations and returns the same object:

```
     // Lets assume here SomeObject contains a function putInt which store a HashMap.
     public static SomeObject createIntEvent(SomeObject objectName,
                                                final String eventName,
                                                final int value){
         objectName.putInt(eventName, value);
         return objectName;
     }
```

2. Static method which creates an object and perform some operations and returns the created Object:

```
     // Lets assume here SomeObject contains a function putInt which store a HashMap.
     public static SomeObject createIntEvent(final String eventName,
                                                final int value){
         SomeObject objectName = new SomeObject();
         objectName.putInt(eventName, value);
         return objectName;
     }
```

For the above two examples, For Case 2 we should have createIntEvent as a synchronized method because we are creating a new object and if it is not thread safe it could cause unwanted problems. But for the case 1, I wasn't certain if the same logic applies.

Can someone please explain why the first Case should or shouldn't be synchronized?

I tried creating a sample program to do the same thing, didn't face any issue. But was wondering if there is some Design pattern which advocates this.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Locking is needed a method modifies state (ie data) that's shared by multiple threads. The second method doesn't modify any shared state, it creates and returns a new object. As for the first, we can't know whether `SomeObject` is shared among multiple threads. If it is, yes, locking is needed but it should be in `putInt`, not an external method that doesn't know how the object is used

Comment: Got it, to answer your question on:
`we can't know whether SomeObject is shared among multiple threads?`

Each function calling this function would have a separate `someObject` and it wouldn't be shared among others.
Thank you for answering @PanagiotisKanavos.

Comment: unless `SomeObject` is thread-safe by itself, the first method does require syncronization.
the second method does not require syncronization, as the object is created by the calling thread, and is not shared with other threads